# SharePoint REST calls with Apache HttpClient and Load Balancing fails after first GET

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, apache-httpclient-4.x

I stumbled on an issue with SharePoint REST calls to a load balancer. When I send the REST calls directly to the webserver, everything seems to work just fine. However, when the REST calls are sent to the load balancer, only the first call gets a HTTP 200 OK status, the rest returns HTTP 401 Unauthorized. After some research I found [this article](https://blog.crsw.com/2008/10/14/unauthorized-401-1-exception-calling-web-services-in-sharepoint/) which says:

*This isn’t a bug.  There was a security fix built into the Windows networking stack that prevents a machine name that resolves to the loopback address from accepting a connection unless that machine name matches the NETBIOS name.*

The only workaround stated in that article, is to change the configuration of the servers, which is not a thing our department is willing to do.

The goal would be that we can do SharePoint REST calls from a Java application.

As an example, I made a small test program to that does a GET request to my SharePoint REST API when I press a button.

When I adjust my Windows hosts file to map the load balance url to an ip address of one of our webservers (under the load balancer), everything seems to work just fine:

```
//first button click
Executing request GET https://lbserver.domain.com/sites/my_site/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Registratielijst')/Items('1') HTTP/1.1
[principal: domain.com\<username>] [workstation: <LBSERVER>]
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

//second button click
Executing request GET https://lbserver.domain.com/sites/my_site/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Registratielijst')/Items('1') HTTP/1.1
[principal: domain.com\<username>] [workstation: <LBSERVER>]
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

However, as soon as we comment out the mapping (and the requests go to the load balancer), the issues start to happen.

```
//first button click
Executing request GET https://lbserver.domain.com/sites/my_site/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Registratielijst')/Items('1') HTTP/1.1
[principal: domain.com\<username>] [workstation: <LBSERVER>]
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

//second button click
Executing request GET https://lbserver.domain.com/sites/my_site/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Registratielijst')/Items('2') HTTP/1.1
[principal: domain.com\<username>] [workstation: <LBSERVER>]
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

As you can see, the first GET request runs just fine. After that, I get the HTTP 401 Unauthorized error.

Why is the HttpClient losing it's authentication/session (as the first request ran fine) even thou the authentication data is inside the HttpContext? Is there anything I am missing in my client code to fix this?

---

**Update:**

When calling openClient() and closeClient() inside the get() method, both GET requests work fine. But it shouldn't be necessary to recreate the httpClient I assume?

---

**Below is the code in full:**

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
CredentialsProvider credsProvider;
HttpClientContext context;
HttpHost targetHost;

Account account;

private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    get("https://lbserver.domain.com/sites/my_site/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Registratielijst')/Items('1')");
}

private void get(String uri) throws IOException {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);

    System.out.println("\nExecuting request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, httpget, context);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

    response.close();
}

private void openClient() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Open client");

    httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    targetHost = new HttpHost("lbserver.domain.com", 443, "https");
    context = HttpClientContext.create();

    credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(targetHost, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "ntlm"), 
            new NTCredentials(account.getUsername(), account.getPassword(), "lbserver", "domain.com"));

    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    context.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
}

private void closeClient() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Close client");
    if (httpClient != null) {
        httpClient.close();
    }
}

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    account = new Account();

    try {
        openClient();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            closeClient();
            return null;
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I found out the issue was caused by wrong cookie handling. The cause was Apache HTTP Client using `CookieSpecs.DEFAULT` (RFC2109). After changing this to `CookieSpecs.STANDARD` (RFC6265), it worked.

```
RequestConfig localConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
            .setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.NTLM))
            .build();

httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore())
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(localConfig)
            .build();
```